# How to change default elqount pagination query string to something else page=?

Tags: laravel

By default laravel elqount pagination uses page= query string to change the current page, I need to change it to i_page_number, how its possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Model::paginate(10, ['*'], 'your_page_name');
```

See pagination method signature :

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null){}
```

OR

```
Model::paginate(10)->setPageName('your_page_name');
```

Unfortunately, its not well documented in Laravel's documentation. You can check the Class [`Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php`](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/AbstractPaginator.php) for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to do this globally? I mean its not good practice to do this on every pagination method